# Is there a notation for the inverse image function itself?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let $f$ be a function.

If $B \subset im(f)$ then the inverse image of $B$ under $f$ in the current standard notation is

$f^{-1}(B) = \{x \in dom(f) : f(x) \in B\}$.

But $f^{-1}$ does not denote the inverse image function !

Using a kind of the typed lambda notation the inverse image function
-- the name $preim$ (from preimage) may be used - can be defined as follows:

$preim := F[B \in P(im(f)), \{x \in dom(f): f(x) \in B \}]$.

But in the common case (if $f$ is not necessary bijective):

$f^{-1} = F[y \in im(f)), \{x \in dom(f): f(x) = y \}]$.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, there isn't a widely used non-conflating notation; just like there isn't  one for the *direct image* function that sends $A\subseteq\mathrm{dom}(f)$ to $f(A)=\{f(a)\mid a\in A\}\subseteq \mathrm{codom}(f)$. One is expected to know from context that you are refering to the direct or inverse image function, since the function and its inverse (when they exist) are applied to *elements*, while the direct image and inverse image induced functions are applied to *subsets*. Note that the inverse image is usually understood to be defined on any subset of the codomain, not just image

Comment: As Halmos notes when introducing the direct image function, "The notation is bad but not catastrophic. What is bad about it is that if $A$ happens to be both an element and a subset of $X$ (an unlikely situation, but far from an impossible one), then the symbol $f(A)$ is ambiguous. Does it mean the value of $f$ at $A$ or does it meant he set of values of $f$ at elements of $A$? Following normal mathematical custom, we shall use the bad notation, relying on context, and, on the rare occasions when it is necessary, adding verbal stipulations, to avoid confusion." From *Naive Set Theory*.

Comment: That's where square brackets help instead of parenthesis. As in Arturo's comment,, $f(A)$ would mean the value of $f$ at the element $A$, while $f[A]$ would be the set of values of $f$ at elements of $A$.

Comment: I like the use of square brackets to indicate type too, but absolutely none of this stuff is standard enough to avoid requiring explanation (for example if you are teaching it). I have seen some very weird notations with arrows and things for this. I (personally!) think they're worse than the conflating notation.

Answer (score 2):

Some common notations for the [converse of a relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_relation) $R$:
$R^\text{T}$, $\breve{R}$, $\check{R}$.

Now these aren't *quite* what you're asking for. As you note, if $f:X\rightarrow Y$, then the function mapping $P(X)\rightarrow P(Y)$ (powersets) is different. However, another standard notation for $f(A)$, with $A\subseteq X$, is $f``A$. So you might write
$$\breve{f}``$$
for your function. I admit I've never seen this particular combination in print.